# Reading records on STDIN is producing uninitialized value errors

Tags: perl, stdin

I want to read records interactively on stdin. CTRL+D marks the end of the record. It goes on forever until ctrl+c is pressed. My code is producing the following errors:

```
Use of uninitialized value in open 
Use of uninitialized value in <HANDLE>
```

Errors can be avoiding by testing $rec, which I have to do to skip null records. But I feel like I am masking an issue I don't quite understand. I suspect stdin is getting closed, but I am not sure. Can you explain why the errors happen and how to fix my loop?

```
my $eof = $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR;
while (1) {
  local $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = chr(0x04);
  my $rec = <STDIN>;

  # format last record that ended with ^D
  local $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = $eof;
  open my $input, "<", \$rec;    
  my_formatting_func $input;
  close $input;
}
```

Comment: `format`? On a file handle? What do you think this does?

Comment: I wanted to change my real function name for something else. I didn't suspect format was an actual perl function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't work anyway, as `format` expects an output filehandle name and a picture format as its parameters, and you are supplying it with an input file handle reference.

However, the problem is that the control-D is handled by the C library before the Perl program ever sees it. It causes the stream to be closed, and subsequent calls to `readfile` will return `undef`.

Just write

```
last unless defined $rec;
```

and you will get the complete input record. Best of all, use the usual idiom and write

```
{
    my $eof = $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR;
    local $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR;
    while (my $rec = <STDIN>) {
        local $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = $eof;
        open my $input, "<", \$rec;    
        format $input;
        close $input;
    }
}
```